# Extjs viewport not rendering

Tags: extjs

Hi i have a viewport with two region west and center west holds panel for tree and center is a tabpanel iam usin the applyTo:div to render the panels but the problem is the jsp page im rendering to already has a header and footer when i render the viewport it goes out of the browser view and also iam not able scroll down to see all the contents..is some one has any idea about this please help...

Comment: Why are you using applyTo with a viewport? Your panels are just part of the config there should be no need to manually apply or render them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [ExtJS docs state](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/):

> The Viewport renders itself to the
>   document body, and automatically sizes
>   itself to the size of the browser
>   viewport and manages window resizing

So you don't need a viewport in this case: just render a panel with a border layout into the same div as you were rendering the viewport. Size the div with CSS so it takes up the area between the header and footer.